# Jquery, PHP and Ajax form without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to prepare simple contact form with jquery, ajax and php without refresh. Everything works fine besides `event.preventDefault();`

That's my files:

contact_engine.php

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    ...


    $from = 'from'; 
    $to = 'to'; 
    $subject = 'subject';
    $human = '4';

    $body = ".........";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            echo '<p>Thanks</p>'; 
        } else { 
        echo '<p>Error</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

Ajax/jQuery

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax('.../contact_engine.php', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/contact_engine.php">       
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="pola formbg name" placeholder="Name" />
            .
            .
            .
            .

            <p><input id="form-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
            </div>
            <br style="clear: left;" />
    </form>
```

When I remove `event.preventDefault();` everything is ok, I receive a message from form but site are refreshing and I see 'thanks' message.

I used Wordpress as you probably seen.

Comment: You have tagged wordpress so you can take a look in https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins I don't believe that your ajax url is working $.ajax('.../contact_engine.php',

Comment: Please note that you have an apparent typo in your URL. Unless you created a directory named `...`, it should be `../contact_engine.php`, not `.../contact_engine.php`.

Comment: You have to use just 2 dots in here, not 3: `$.ajax('.../contact_engine.php'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in this kind of instance why have a form/submit button.
Remove the form and change the input from a submit button to a standard button.
Put the function on the button, job done.

```
$('#form-button').on('click', function(event){

    $.ajax('.../contact_engine.php', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
           //do something with the return code
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an ID - I think the problem is your submit handler does is not firing:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {...
```

and then change your jQuery to read:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: When I did it, form works fine but still with refresh even with 'event.preventDefault();'. But thanks for idea.